# Adding Scala generic bound to a function which hasn't it in upperclass

Tags: scala, generics

Here's my problem

```
trait T {
  def f[A](a: A): Double
}

trait T2 extends T {
  def f[A <: Seq[Double]](a: A): Double
}
```

Rise the following error :

```
overriding method f in trait T of type [A](a: A)Double;
method f has incompatible type
```

I understand that i add a new constraint to the method but don't get the whole picture

It seems to work as follow but from what are said in comments it's not a resolution at all.

```
trait T {
  def f[A](a: A): Double
}

trait T2 extends T {
  def f[A](a: A)(implicit ev: A <:< Seq[Double]): Double
}
```

I would like to know if it exist a way to go through this.

Comment: Your `T` guarantees that it has a method `f` that works for all possible `A`. Your `T2` cannot extend `T`, because it does not work for all possible `A` (it works only on subtypes of sequences). Are you sure that you wanted `T` to work for all possible `A`, instead of specifying that there *exists* `A` such that `f` is applicable to it? If this is not the case, then there is no solution. But it looks like XY-problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. If you wish to override a method, you can't narrow its possible inputs. Maybe something like this could work for you:

```
trait T[A] {
  def f(a: A): Double
}

trait T2 extends T[Seq[Double]] {
  def f(s: Seq[Double]): Double
}
```